# Проблема с SCOPED_SESSION sqlalchemy в python 3.11

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Я столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу понять, как решить.

Есть приложение на flask. Для него написано множество тестов.
Есть фиксы db_session и db_scoped_session, включая глобальную переменную SCOPED_SESSION. Обработчики реализованы в виде представлений.

Упомянутые фиксы - db_session и db_scoped_session и объект SCOPED_SESSION - это разные объекты, судя по id. Это справедливо как для ранней - python 3.9, так и для новой - 3.11, на которую мы перешли. С ранней версией python проблем не возникло, а с версией python 3.11 тесты падали, основной причиной чего стала ошибка - DetachedInstanceError.

Читайте подробнее об этой ошибке.

Она возникает, когда мы пытаемся получить доступ к объекту, отделенному от его сессии.

Когда объект загружается в сессию, он находится в персистентном состоянии - это означает, что любые изменения отслеживаются сессией. Когда сессия закрывается, объекты, связанные с ней, переходят в состояние detached, что и приводит к вышеуказанной ошибке.

1. Полагая, что ошибка связана с тем, что мы используем разные сессии для фикстур и для самих представлений, я перенес все фикстуры в одну сессию. Это не помогло:)
2. Сессия очищается в вызываемом методе teardown_appcontext - объектом __remove_session. Удаление этого метода устранило эту проблему, но вызвало новые проблемы другого характера.

Версия sqlalchemy - 1.3.28.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Пример

```
# view.py
class SomeView:
    def get_one(self, id):
        return some_thing

# flask_app.py
from flask_admin import Admin
from view import SomeView

admin = Admin(...)

admin.add_view(SomeView(...), endpoint='/some_endpoint/')

# worker.py

class Worker(...):
    def _init_application(self):
        self._flask_app = Flask(...)
        ...
        self._flask_app.teardown_appcontext(self._remove_session)
        ...
    def _remove_session(self, response_or_exc):
        SCOPED_SESSION.remove()
        return response_or_exc

# test_case.py

def test_edit_get(test_object, client:FlaskClient, request_headers) -> None:

        response: TestResponse = client.get(
            f'/some_endpoint/?id={test_object.id}',
            headers=request_headers
        )
        assert response.status_code == 200
        # Error coming here
        print(test_object.id) # DetachedInstanceError
```

Comment: Спасибо, это опечатка была. Поправил

Comment: Хорошо, а собственно `test_object` откуда берётся и как ещё используется? Может он используется неоднократно, при этом кто-то закрывает транзакцию перед тем, как он повторно используется? Попробуйте использовать не сам `test_object`, а взять от него `test_object.id`, положить в другую переменную и уже эту переменную дальше в тестах использовать. Вы наверное написали в вопросе как это всё происходит, но я уже не в состоянии разбираться. Короче, есть ли точно у вас необходимость таскать именно объект БД по тестам, если в данном тесте от него только `id` собственно используется?

Comment: Полезный взгляд на решение, попробую и отпишусь обязательно. Спасибо
PS: 
test_object - это фикстура, где объект добавляется в базу и флэшится. 
Там и правда есть дополнительный callable фикстура - assertmixture, в которой перекрестно используется объект. 
Вопрос заключается в том, что в версии 3.9 python все работало, а тут цирк с конями.